# Check Firefox OS version

Tags: javascript, firefox-os

I'm working on a snippet for check the Firefox OS version used.

Now i'm using the gecko version in the user agent string (is different in every version of Firefox OS) but it's not a professional solution often is simple.

The gist:
https://gist.github.com/Mte90/11087561

Any suggestion?

**The gist is updated with the better solution for check the Firefox OS version**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not very nice way to do this but you could parse the user agent

```
 function convertVersionNumber(ver) {
     var hashVersion = {
         '18.0': '1.0.1',
         '18.1': '1.1',
         '26.0': '1.2',
         '28.0': '1.3',
         '30.0': '1.4',
         '32.0': '1.5'
     }
     var rver = ver;
     var sStr = ver.substring(0, 4);
     if (hashVersion[sStr]) {
         rver = hashVersion[sStr];
     }
     return (rver);

 } function getVersion() {
     if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(mobile|tablet)/i)) {
         var ffVersionArray = (navigator.userAgent.match(/Firefox\/([\d]+\.[\w]?\.?[\w]+)/));
         if (ffVersionArray.length === 2) {
             return (convertVersionNumber(ffVersionArray[1]));
         }
     }
     return (null); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks i've updated the gist and combined the two function in only one.

Comment: You should update your `hasVersion` var. Refer to this link
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Answer (score 2):

This is the only way I know to detect the version of Firefox OS right now. If it's [also to see if a feature exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171825/check-if-firefox-firefox-os-firefox-for-android/23198614?noredirect=1#comment35697319_23198614), I would, again, use feature detection instead of version detection.

```
if (navigator.connection) //Network Information API
if (navigator.battery) // Battery Status API
```

If these if return true, it's because those features are available on the version the user run your application on.

Answer (score 0):

In `/gaia/profile/settings.json` can you read the version?

Or use the settings api to read and compare:

```
deviceinfo.platform_version
```

[Firefox OS Settings List](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Platform/Settings_list)

Comment: The Settings API is only for certified application right now.